# How do I continue with this set proof?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, propositional-calculus

[image]

I've drew a Venn diagram and they're obviously equal, but I'm stuck on the last step.

Comment: You seem to be confusing some of the notation. Try to show that for any element $x\in A\cap(B\setminus C),$ it must also hold that $x\in (A\cap B)\setminus(A\cap C),$ using the definitions of these operations. Then try to prove the reverse inclusion.

Comment: But it doesn't make sense to say "$x\in A\cap(x\in B\setminus C)$," because $x\in S$ is saying that the element $x$ is in the set $S$ (that is, it is a proposition), whereas the operations $\cap$ and $\setminus$ are defined for a pair of sets, and the results of these operations yield another set.

Comment: You're mixing up set notation with logic notation.

Comment: @Bram28 can you point where and why? I'm not seeing it, though you're probably right.

Comment: @LtotheV Consider your $x \in A \cap x \in (B - C)$.  The $x \in A$ part is a claim, and so is $x \in (B-C)$, but the $\cap$ is a set operator: it takes two sets.  But you just put it between two claims, as if the $\cap$ is an operator between two claims.  What you *can* do is write something like $x \in A \land x \in (B-C)$:  the $\land$ is a logical operator that works on two claims, and asserts that both are true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using $X - Y = X \cap Y^C$, we get:

$$(A \cap B) - (A\cap C)=$$

$$(A\cap B \cap (A \cap C)^C=$$

$$(A \cap B \cap (A^C \cup C^C)=$$

$$(A \cap B \cap A^C) \cup (A \cap B \cap C^C)=$$

$$\emptyset \cup (A \cap B \cap C^C)=$$

$$A \cap B \cap C^C=$$

$$A \cap (B - C)$$